# How to import CSV data to MySQL in JetBrains DataGrip

Tags: mysql, csv, import, datagrip

I'm studying MySQL. I need to import data from a CSV file to a MySQL table using JetBrains DataGrip.

I've done such this job before in dbForge MySQL, but last week I moved from Windows to Linux.

There are some questions how to import CSV to MySQL on StackOverflow, but I'm still not so familiar with SQL.

How do I import a CSV data file in JetBrains DataGrip?

Thank you!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. Context menu of datasource you want to import to
2. Choose Import from File....
3. Customize the table that will be created, check the preview and press OK.

[image: Context menu]
[image: Import Dialog]

Comment: I tried this and it was taking 280ms per row of a 3 column file. It took 380 seconds for 1321 rows compared to navicat which took 7 seconds to import the same data. Is there a way to speed this up? I want to be able to insert some csv files which contain several million rows of data

Comment: It's quite fast now with 2016.1

Comment: Still very slowwww

Comment: Theja, please file the issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

Answer (score 8):

Precision : The pinned answer explains how to create and populate a **new table**.

To populate an already existing table it's quite similar: use the context menu of this particular table to choose *Import From File*. Then the steps are similar to the ones in the pinned answer.

[image: Right click the table to update then import data from file]

Answer (score 0):

Since this original post. JetBrains has published this page outlining several of DataGrip's Import and Export features.
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/importexport.html